# Android app behaves differently in "recent apps" list when launched from SEND Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a simple Android application that operates on some text data. The app is invoked two ways: 1) launching the app from the launcher and entering the text data manually, or 2) using the SEND intent to share some text with it.

When launched through the launcher, everything behaves as I expect. When launched through the Share feature and subsequently using the app switcher/recent apps button, the application appears as "Android System" and disappears if I switch away from it. I'd like it to appear in that list like any other app and persist when switched away from. So the question is: why does my app behave differently when launched from the different intents? I'm sure there's some fundamental thing I'm not understanding about Intents, Activities and Tasks, but I can't determine where even to look.

Here's the relevant section of the manifest.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.stub2.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example the user calls your activity `Main` with `ACTION_SEND` along with some text `abc`. Another time, he calls `Main` with text `zzz`. Then you will have 2 instances of `Main` in recent list, with different intents.

---

*Edit*

You can register `ACTION_SEND` with an "adapter" activity like `AdapterActivity`, then forward the text to `Main`. By this way, your app (`Main` activity) will be only listed in recent apps if the user starts it from the launcher.

```
<activity
    android:name="AdapterActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true" />
```

There are more activity tags [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Comment: If I follow these steps, I get exactly the same behavior I currently have when handling both intents in the Main activity. What I would like is for both intents (ACTION_MAIN, ACTION_SEND) to cause the same app behavior in the recent apps list. Please note that neither creating a second "Adapter Activity" nor setting FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS prior to starting the Main activity have any effect on this behavior.

Comment: @monkeyfacebag Thanks. I missed something. You can try the solution edited.